# Is it possible to pass "this" by default?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, this

Is it possible to pass `this` by default ?

Here is what I currently have

```
class A
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void dowithT(T t) {}
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;

    B()
    {
        //Calling 'dowithT' with 'this'
        a.dowithT(this);
    }
};
```

This function requires passing `this` from the caller of the function every time. So I wondered if there is a way to encapsulate this task, so that you don't need to pass `this` to `dowithT`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    // '= this' doesn't compile
    template<typename T>
    void dowithT(T t = this) {}
};

class B
{
public:
    A a;

    B()
    {
        //Calling 'dowithT' without 'this'
        a.dowithT();
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I can't use templates, so my first solution isn't an option.

Is this possible?

Edit: I gave a concrete answer with my own implementation below. Also with a few mor deatils of what I wanted in the end.

Comment: You do not need to pass `this` pointer as an argument. It is always present in the context of this class. Try using it directly.

Comment: @MukulGupta: The `this` in question is for `class B`, which is not available to `class A` by default.

Comment: By the way, I think that you should reconsider your class design. *"I wrote a class which requires passing "this" from the caller of the function."* - This just sounds like a real bad idea...

Comment: @Cornstalks: My bad.

Comment: @Christian Hackl: i use "this" as a parameter because i already encapsulated the task of creating : `function<void()> (std::bind(func, res)` with "res" being what is meant for the "this"pointer to be here

Comment: If it suits the design you can pass either `this` or `*this` to `A`s constructor.

Comment: you say "I can't use templates" but your code samples all have templates ?? what does `class A` really look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve exactly what you want by using a private mixin class to provide the `dowithT` method that takes no arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class A
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void dowithT(T* t) {
      std::cout << "Hello, World" << typeid(*t).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class Owner>
  struct calls_a
  {
    void dowithT()
    {
      auto p = static_cast<Owner*>(this);
      p->a.dowithT(p);
    }
  };

class B
  : private calls_a<B>
{
    friend calls_a<B>;
    A a;

public:
    B()
    {
        //Calling 'dowithT' with 'this'
        dowithT();
    }
};

int main()
{
  B b;

}
```

Comment: i could adapt your code into mine and i after i handled all the errors about preexisting templates and .... well i finally got the code to run (i will give an own answer shortly).

Comment: Hmm. Did you copy the code exactly? I copy/pasted it from a complete, working program.

Comment: no i haven't copied your code, but i used what you used

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** No, this is not possible.

`this` is not the same type in every class, you can't generalize it, so no, not possible.

Additionally, what would `this` be if `doWithT()` was called from a non-member function? `nullptr`?

That's why it isn't possible. You have to use a `template`.

Comment: My thoughts where similar, but I wasn't sure. Your Addition shows the basic issue quite good.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `B` having a *member* of type `A`, it can *inherit* from `A`, and use something like the ["curiously recurring template pattern."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

If you cannot make class A a template, you can still do it like so:

```
class A
{
    protected:
    template <class T>
    void dowithT()
    {
         T* callerthis = static_cast<T*>(this);
         // callerthis is the "this" pointer for the inheriting object
         cout << "Foo";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    B()
    {
        dowithT<B>();
        // Or A::dowithT<B>();
    }
};
```

`dowithT()` must only be called by an inheriting class (hence I made it `protected`), with the template parameter the caller's own type, or you'll break everything.

Comment: ok it might work but i also need a function pointer type passed, i need to figure out how to calculate a member function ptr type in the template

Comment: @Meph: for what use? If every caller has a method, say "foo()", that dowithT() should call, then you can just use `callerthis->foo()`

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. There is nothing really special about `this` when used as an argument to a function taking `T*` (template or not), it's just a pointer like any other.

Answer (score 1):

`this A` is different from `this B`. In your first code, `this` refers to the caller, while in the second `this` refers to the `callee`. Thus what you want to do isnt really possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility, which might, or might not suit your needs:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T t) : t(t) {}

    void dowithT()
    {
         cout << "Foo";
    }

private:
    T t;
};

class B
{
    public:
    A<B*> a;

    B() : a(this)
    {
        a.dowithT();
    }
};
```

Comment: This works, yes, but as mentioned i cannot use templates with class A

Comment: class A resembles a class in my code which is callable and can be loaded with functions, so that i might select one of them and it can bring its own ressources. To stay short here : A has always to be the same type so that i can use its full functionality in an array of A's. If there where templates, it is not possible to write them all to the array

Answer (score 0):

You could use a private method in class B that acts as a relay, and use the constant nullptr as a special value for this, if you want to be able to pass other values:

```
class B
{
public:
    A a;

    B()
    {
        //Calling 'dowithT' with 'this'
        innerdo();
    }
private:
    void innerdo(B *p = nullptr) {
        if (p == nullptr) p = this;
        a.dowithT(p);
    }
};
```

If you only need to pass `this` it is even simpler

```
    void innerdo() {
        a.dowithT(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying out various things you mentioned, I'd like to give my answer/solution to the problem myself to clarify some details:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <functional>

template <typename CallerType>
class AFunctionConstructor{
private:
    virtual void abstr()
    {}
public:
    
    typedef void(CallerType::*CallerTypeFunc)();

    function<void()>* constructFunction(CallerTypeFunc func)
    {
        CallerType* newMe = dynamic_cast<CallerType*> (this);
        return new function<void()>(std::bind(func,newMe));
    }       
};

class A : public function<void()>
{
protected:
    
     
public:
    A();
    A(function<void()>* func) : function<void()>(*func)
    {}

};


//  now create ressource classes
//  they provide functions to be called via an object of class A

class B : public AFunctionConstructor<B>
{
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "Foo";
    }

public:
    A a;

    B() : a(constructFunction(&B::foo)) {}
};

class C : public AFunctionConstructor < C >
{
    void bar()
    {
        cout << "Bar";
    }

public:
    A a;

    C() : a(constructFunction(&C::bar)) {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;

    b.a(); 
    c.a();

    cout << endl;

    A* array[5];

    array[0] = &b.a;        //different functions with their ressources
    array[1] = &c.a;        
    array[2] = &b.a;
    array[3] = &c.a;
    array[4] = &c.a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)     //this usability i wanted to provide
    {
        (*(array[i]))();
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

> FooBar
>
> FooBarFooBarBar

This is as far as i can press it down concerning examples. But i guess this is unsafe code. I stumbled across possible other and simpler ways to achieve this (other uses of std::function and lambdas(which i might have tried to reinvent here partially it seems)).

At first I had tried to pass "this" to the bind function in `function<void()>*AFunctionConstructor::constructFunction(CallerTypeFunc func)`
,though, which i now get through the dynamic upcast.
Additionally the functionality  of `AFunctionConstructor` was first supposed to be implemented in a Constructor of A.